# asp.net button click do a postback but not fire the event on server prod (it works fine on local)

Tags: c#, asp.net, production-environment

The click event works just fine on local, and not on production server, I have the postback when the button is clicked but it doesen't fire the button's event.

I've already spent 3 days seeking the problem with no result, please any idea ?

This is my simple code in page aspx:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="BtnChangeLang_Click" 
 ID="BtnChangeLang" />
```

and the event method in code behind :

```
 public void BtnChangeLang_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //// my code   
 }
```

Thank you for ur help.

Comment: Are you sure you have deployed all the files you need to production? Any change in code behind requires to update the DLL, not just aspx.

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes i did, after every modification in my code behind i rebuild the package and replace the dll in the server, i've created a new website project  with only one button and click event in code behind and put this on the server, it did not work, i think there something to add to the webconfig or to configure in the server,

Comment: and how's your form tag?

Comment: Below is my form tag                                                                               
     <form runat="server">

Comment: i'm using a master page, i've tried to add an action but it did not work

Comment: does this only happen with one button? do you have other weforms and controls working in production? also which template have you used? (web application or website)

Comment: no this happens with all my buttons, i'm using a webapplication

Comment: Web applications are compiled or precompiled so you need to check which version of MS Framework you're running at server and this should support the one used for compiling the DLL locally. Open IIS, go to application pools and find the one that is running your app.